# C# Windows Service With Command Line Access/REPL?

Tags: c#, wcf, service, windows-services

This is my first time dabbling in windows services.

I have a service I would like to manage, I would like to be able to connect to this service via a command line / REPL of sorts to avoid the development time of working on a user interface. I was thinking we could communicate much like attaching to an Asterisk daemon or somewhat like connecting to a MySQL server which to me seems like nothing more than a simple custom shell spawned to handle requests. However, I am always concerned about how efficient my code is and would like to keep to common practices. This will be connecting on the same local machine.

My proposed solution:
I believe I can make simple network stream, to create a simple Read - Eval - Print - Loop.

Another option is to use WCF, however my question would then be, how efficient is this as opposed to packet handling?

**My question:**
What are some standard practices for communicating with or managing services on the local machine?

I'm trying to learn more about service-oriented design, any resources that could help explain common practice models would be much appreciated.

Comment: When you say service what do you mean?  If you want to see the output just use log4net and add an appender of your flavor.  Is this a web service, windows service, domain service... ?

Comment: I apologize, it is a windows service.

Comment: In the past, when creating a windows service; I create the application one layer abstracted away from the service.  This gives you the ability to run it using a win service wrapper or a console app wrapper.

Answer (score 0):

Of course there are so many ways to do this.  The way I would recommend is to make sure you use log4net (or some other logging framework) and log the important info.  Create the solution with 3 projects, the first will be the "service logic" or the business service, with the second being the windows service wrapper that starts that service, and the third being a console app that does much the same as the windows service only giving you the ability to interact as you wish.  The advantage of the console logging appender is that you still get the console output without actually writing to the console... it give good separation.

I will give another option that I have used in the past, but would give with caution.  You can [selfhost a WCF service](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms731758%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) inside a windows service.  It gives a nice interface that gets away form the messy self rolled TCP server approach.  The caution is that if done wrong it can eat up lots of memory and CPU cycles.